# check nested key existence in video object in youtube-api to avoid NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Tags: java, json, youtube-data-api

I want to check the existence of nested key in `Video` object returned as a Json response from youtube video search by using below code:-

```
YouTube.Videos.List searchvideostats = youtube.videos().list("snippet,statistics");
searchvideostats.setKey(apiKey);
Video v = searchvideostats.execute().getItems().get(0);
System.out.println(v.toPrettyString());
```

I got output like this:-

```
{
  "etag" : "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/-TONXAYMx_10Caihcoac4XCyb4I\"",
  "id" : "4Aa9GwWaRv0",
  "kind" : "youtube#video",
  "snippet" : {
    "categoryId" : "10",
...................
.........
```

MY goal is:- how to check whether **categoryId** key is present in this response or not. coz if do `v.getSnippet().getCategoryId()` it gives **NullPointerException** if categotyId is not present in Json.

Tried:-

```
if (v.containsKey("id")) {
                   System.out.println("contains");
} else {
          System.out.println("doesnt contains");
}
```

this returns **contains** as expected.

```
if (v.containsKey("categoryId")) {
                   System.out.println("contains");
} else {
          System.out.println("doesnt contains");
}
```

This returns **doesnt contains**.. which is not expected. How would I check if this nested key is available?

P.S. -> I have to check many nested such keys.

Thanks for help.

Comment: No one has faced this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need String manipulations. Just use Youtube library.

```
if(video.getSnippet()!=null && video.getSnippet().getCategoryId()!=null)
```

will do the stuff.

note: checking for zero length categoryid might be necessary also.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have updated my question, included issue which I am facing. this will give me nullpointerexception.

Comment: will try and will get back to you